# Typo3 8.7: Different mail templates for form finisher EmailToReceiver / EmailToSender

Tags: forms, typo3, email-templates, typo3-8.x

I'm using the Typo3 form-module (sysext) with two email-finishers: EmailToReceiver vs. EmailToSender. I set up a custom mailtemplate, but

- HOW can I select different mailtemplates for this two different mails?
- OR is there another way to send two different mails?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to Mathias Brodala's correct answer, you can also use `templateName` and `templateRootPaths` inside each email finisher. It will respect the email format you set with `options.format` if configured like below:

```
finishers:
  -
    identifier: EmailToReceiver
    options:
      subject: 'E-Mail from website'
      recipientAddress: your.company@example.com
      recipientName: 'Your Company name'
      senderAddress: '{email}'
      senderName: '{lastname}'
      replyToAddress: ''
      carbonCopyAddress: ''
      blindCarbonCopyAddress: ''
      format: html
      attachUploads: 'true'
      templateName: '{@format}.html'
      templateRootPaths:
        20: 'EXT:your_extension/Resources/Private/Forms/Emails/Receiver/'
      translation:
        language: ''
  -
    identifier: EmailToSender
    options:
      subject: 'Your message'
      recipientAddress: '{email}'
      recipientName: '{lastname}'
      senderAddress: your.company@example.com
      senderName: 'Your Company name'
      replyToAddress: ''
      carbonCopyAddress: ''
      blindCarbonCopyAddress: ''
      format: html
      attachUploads: 'true'
      templateName: '{@format}.html'
      templateRootPaths:
        20: 'EXT:your_extension/Resources/Private/Forms/Emails/Sender/'
```

According to the file paths set above, the templates are then saved in

- **your_extension/Resources/Private/Forms/Emails/Sender/**
  *Html.html* or *Plaintext.html*
- **your_extension/Resources/Private/Forms/Emails/Receiver/**
  *Html.html* or *Plaintext.html*

The complete tutorial can be found [here](https://www.sebkln.de/en/tutorials/different-e-mail-templates-for-emailtosender-and-emailtoreceiver-finishers-in-ext-form/).

On GitHub is [a working TYPO3 extension](https://github.com/sebkln/form_examples) with several example forms, including a form with custom mail template only for the sender.

Comment: that's very detailed and helpful

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`templatePathAndFilename`](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/form/latest/Config/proto/finishersDefinition/finishers/EmailToReceiver.html#options-templatepathandfilename) finisher option to set a custom template for your mails. You can set this for each finisher separately:

```
finishers:
  - identifier: EmailToReceiver
    options:
      # ...
      templatePathAndFilename: EXT:my_site/Resources/Private/Templates/.../EmailToReceiver.html

  - identifier: EmailToSender
    options:
      # ...
      templatePathAndFilename: EXT:my_site/Resources/Private/Templates/.../EmailToSender.html
```

Comment: Yes, I edited this value. So I set ONE template for both EmailToReceiver and EmailToSender. I need different tempates for this two cases.

Comment: You can set the `templatePathAndFilename` inside each of the email finishers. This allows you to set different paths and use different mail templates.

Comment: @mathias-brodala: But this way you are not able to make a difference between HTML and PLAINTEXT format, wright?

Comment: You're already choosing the mail format with `options.format` inside the finisher configuration. Besides that, you can also set `templateRootPaths` as shown here: http://www.sklein-medien.de/en/tutorials/detail/different-e-mail-templates-for-emailtosender-and-emailtoreceiver-finishers-in-extform/ – `templateName: '{@format}.html'` will respect the format option, then.

Comment: This is working fine, thanks. In addition: to change per form one could edit the files {formname}.yaml in fileadmin/user_upload/ (default path for conf-files made with the BE-form-editor).

Comment: Getting error "The option "subject" must be set for the EmailFinisher. " could your please help me to fix

Comment: *Did* you set a subject?